# Detect intersection nodes between different highway types

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, intersection

I have a postgres database with OSM data imported in it using osmosis. The import process created a **ways** table that has the following columns:

id | version | user_id | tstamp | changeset_id | tags | nodes | linestring

The **tags** column contains all the OSM tags on that specific way, including the **highway=*** tag. The **nodes** column constains all the OSM nodes that are part of that way.

I'm interested in finding all the nodes that are basically the intersection node between a **highway=primary** and **highway=secondary**, for example, or whatever highway-highway combination.

How can I make use of the **tags** and **nodes** columns?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I would have a look at https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting it handles most of this already. You can probably postprocess and find the highways of interest after the topology is created.